# How can I add each newly connected object to every object's list in C#?

Tags: c#, loops, unity-game-engine

I want 'Bool A' to return true if Building A is connected to Building G. Buildings B, C, D, E and F are between them.

Is there like a recursive loop situation that lets me go through each connected building and add every connected building to Building A's "connected buildings" list?

Note: each building has a list of "buildings I am currently connected to".

[building A] -- [building B] -- [building C] -- [building D] -- [building E]

Currently, they buildings only recognise their immediate neighbours/children.

Any help for this noob greatly appreciated.

Comment: It depends on your implementation of the connectivity of the buildings. Can you add your current code that does that first level connection?

Comment: We need to see the code. We need to see what you have tried, what the output is and what the output should be

Comment: Linked lists come to mind: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.linkedlist-1?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Or if you get the building instances from outside and they only have information about their immediate neighbors, a recursive approach can help.

Comment: have you lot of building?  its important to know that, because the way to coding could be different..

Comment: This sounds like a data structure question rather then an implementation issue ... Totally depends on your usecase. If you beforehand know all buildings it might be best to have a Dictionary where every building can store whether it is connected nested to a specific building or not ...

Comment: Hi Marc. I suggest you show some code.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a `Building` object made of a `NeighbourBuildings` property which is a collection of all the buildings directly connected to that building, and a `ConnectedBuildings` property which is a collection of all the buildings directly and indirectly connected to that building.

Then, when calling the getter of `ConnectedBuildings`, you return a new collection which contains the building plus an aggregate of the `ConnectedBuildings` collections of all the `ConnectedBuildings`.

Then you will notice the recursive loop never stops because it travels back and forth between buildings. For example: B is connected to C, which is connected to B, which is connected to C, etc. So in order to resolve this, you need to add a **notion of parent**: each building will become the parent or child of another building. Each building has only one parent, but as many child as necessary. This way you start to **build a tree**, and only call the child buildings of a parent building, never the other way around, so that your recursive loop will come to an end once a child building does not have any children.

Some proposed architecture:

- `ParentBuilding` = the parent of that building.
- `ChildBuildings` = the collection of child buildings which are connected to this building.
- `AllChildBuildings` =  `ChildBuildings.Select(building =>
  building.AllChildBuildings)`
- `ConnectedBuildings` = `ParentBuilding` + `ChildBuildings` (not necessary but to help you understand the architecture)

Each node (here a building) will contain a reference to all the nodes it is a direct or indirect parent of. Depending on the performance you are looking for, you may consider calculating the tree only once, or each time you make a call.

Finally, make sure you never end up with a circle, where A is parent of B, which is parent of C, which is parent of A: you would not have a tree any more and the recursive call would be infinite once again.